# Ubuntu 6.06 Boot problem

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I tried to boot my pc(4 yr old one) using ubuntu 6.06 in the live cd mode but it refuses to boot. It throws the error

```
Uncompressing Linux.. ok, booting from kernel
[   54.168828] ACPI Unable to load the System Descriptor Tables
```

The live cd works perfectly okay in other computers.

Out of curiosity, I also tried to boot using Slax live cd, It too threw some errors

```
incomplete literal tree
invalid compressed format (err=1)
UDF-fs: No partition found (1)
XFS: bade magic number
XFS: SB validate failed
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0)
```

The slax errors are a bit worrying to me.

These two distros used to work perfectly in this pc just a couple of days ago.

Thanks for the help in advance!

**Update 1** : I checked it using ubuntu 8.04 too, It throws the same error as 6.06

Answer (score 1):

Try booting without ACPI!

Add the phrase `acpi=off noacpi` to the boot options line as you boot. (When you see the option about try Ubuntu, install, etc, press `F6` (I think, look for something like "Boot options" at the bottom of the screen, then `Esc`, and add that phrase to the end of the boot options.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but I had a similar issue earlier when tried to run Fedora 4 on a relatively new machine.

it seems that the old OS does not support the new hardware

Comment: The computer is equally old too, Ubuntu 6.06 used to work perfectly fine in this pc but today it suddenly stopped working!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that certain methods of accessing the BIOS that the old version of Linux is looking to use are no longer supported on modern machines.

Have you tried using a newer version of the [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have new versions of ubuntu(downloads not cheap in this part of the world), but 6.06 worked well just a few days ago. Ive been using 6.06 for quite some years.

Answer (score 0):

Check the BIOS has ACPI enabled.

Comment: Yes, It's enabled.